# Creating SQL query to return oldest date for event and duration until different event

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, ado, duration

I am trying to write an SQL query (querying Access from Excel using ADO) to return each distinct UserID together with the **oldest** date for the EventID=916 and the **earliest** date for EventID=944 occuring for this user after the 916 event. Additionally, I would like to calculate the duration in days between the dates.

Test data is as follows:

```
create table table_name
(
  EventID int,
  UserId int,
  MsgVar1 varchar(4),
  MsgVar2 varchar(4),
  EventDate date
);

insert into table_name (EventId,UserId,MsgVar1,MsgVar2,EventDate) values 
(916,123456,'x', 'x','20110920'),
(944,123456,'x','x','20110923'),
(945,123456,'x','x','20110925'),
(916,123456,'x', 'x','20110928'),
(944,123456,'x', 'x','20110928'),
(916,123458,'x', 'x','20110919'),
(944,123458,'x','x','20110928');
```

The query should return is the following:

```
UserId | Event916Date | Event944Date | Duration
-----------------------------------------------
123456 | 20110920     | 20110923     | 3
123458 | 20110919     | 20110928     | 9
```

My starting point is as follows, however right now this returns **all** 944 events rather than just the oldest.

```
select start.UserID, start.EventDate start, end.EventDate end, datediff(end.EventDate, start.EventDate) duration
from (
    select *, (
        select UserID from table_name L2 where L2.EventDate>L1.EventDate and L2.UserId=L1.UserId order by EventDate limit 1
    ) stop_id from table_name L1
) start
join table_name end on end.UserID=start.stop_id
where start.EventID=916 and end.EventID=944;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test data does not match your expected results.  The `latest` date for eventID 916 is 20110928 and userID 123456 and the `earliest` 944 date for that user after that date is also 20110928 just from looking at the sample data provided.  I removed those last event id of 916 for user 123456 and was able to get the expected results.

I changed your test data to the following:

```
insert into table_name (EventId,UserId,MsgVar1,MsgVar2,EventDate) values
(944,123456,'x','x','20110910'),
(916,123456,'x','x','20110920'),
(944,123456,'x','x','20110923'),
(945,123456,'x','x','20110925'),
(944,123456,'x','x','20110928'),
(916,123458,'x','x','20110919'),
(944,123458,'x','x','20110928');
```

The closest I came to your results with a single query is below, but it does not work as you can not use an aliased result from one subquery in the subsequent subquery.  Perhaps someone else will give you a one query answer as it seems this should be doable.

```
select t1.userID, 
(select max(eventdate) from table_name t2 where t1.userid = t2.userid and eventid = 916) as Event916Date
from table_Name t1, 
(select t3.userID, 
(select min(eventdate) from table_name t4 where t4.userid = t3.userid and eventid = 944 and eventDate >= t1.Event916Date) as Event944Date
from table_Name t3) as t2
group by t1.userID
```

In access I was able to accomplish this using a few queries.

**T1:** Get the maximum event date for event 916 and each user

```
SELECT table_name.UserId, Max(table_name.EventDate) AS MaxOfEventDate
FROM table_name
GROUP BY table_name.UserId, table_name.EventID
HAVING (((table_name.EventID)=916));
```

**T2:** Get the event dates for 944 and each user that are greater than your minimum

```
SELECT t1.UserId, table_name.EventDate
FROM table_name INNER JOIN t1 ON table_name.UserId = t1.UserId
WHERE (((table_name.EventDate)>[maxofeventdate]) AND ((table_name.eventId)=944));
```

**T3:** get the min event date of 944 for each user

```
SELECT t2.UserId, Min(t2.EventDate) AS MinOfEventDate
FROM t2
GROUP BY t2.UserId;
```

**T4:** final query to display both and calculate the duration

```
SELECT t1.UserId, t1.MaxOfEventDate, t3.MinOfEventDate, [MinOfEventDate]-[MaxOfEventDate] AS Duration
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t3 ON t1.UserId = t3.UserId;
```

If you are using ADO from excel you should have access to the querydef object to be able to create and use multiple queries.